# WebSocket Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, websocket

I want to Create WebSocket Example in which i do not want to refresh the page for getting latest data.

I Create one Html page in which create one object of websocket.

E.g

### ClientSide Implementation

```
 var ws = new WebSocket(hostURL);

 ws.onopen = function ()
      {
                // When Connection Open
      };
ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     {
        // When Any Response come from WebSocket
     }
 ws.onclose = function (e) 
   { 
       // OnClose of WebSocket Conection
   }
```

### Server Side Implementation

```
public class WebSocketManager : WebSocketHandler
{
     private static WebSocketCollection WebSocketObj4AddMessage = new WebSocketCollection();

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
      // Do when Connection Is Open
    }

    public override void OnClose()
    {
       // Close Connection
    }
    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        // When Any Message Sent to Client
    }
}
```

Is I am doing right way to use WebSocket ?

Please help me to clear out in this section.

Comment: were did error comes

Comment: Is this way of web socket implementation is right ? am i going in right way of web socket.

Comment: what is your exact requirement

Comment: Hey Anand , I want just clarify wheather my implementation of WebSocket feature is correct or not for getting latest data without refresh.

Comment: i dont how to clarify his question, so that i placed a simple program for his understanding

Comment: I create one App that makes Active/InActive status and we display that status on our web app and want to get latest status without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample. 
First you have to install `Asp.net SignalR` package along with its dependenies.
You have call the SignalR when the app starts

```
namespace ABC
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR(); <--{Add this line}
        }        
    }
}
```

You have start the `SqlDependency` when app start and stop when app stops in the `Global.asax` file.

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringsName"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionString);
        }
        protected void Application_End()
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(ConnectionString);
        }
```

You have to create custom `Hubclass` extending `Hub Base class`

```
public class MessagesHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("sendMessages")]
    public void SendMessages()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
        context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
    }
}
```

Then in the client page, you have add these code in the `javascript` section

```
   $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;
        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
            getAllMessages()
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            getAllMessages();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });
    function getAllMessages() {
            $.ajax({
               url: '../../Notifications/GetNotificationMessages',
               .
               .
       }
```

The server call this function when there there is any change in the `database table` using `sqlDependency`
The `getAllMessages()` is the controller for your code to handle, that should be shown in the view page and it will be call when the app starts and any change in db

```
public ActionResult GetNotificationMessages()
        {
            NotificationRepository notification = new NotificationRepository();
            return PartialView("_NotificationMessage");
        }
```

The in `model` class

```
public class NotificationRepository
    {
        readonly string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InexDbContext"].ConnectionString;

        public IEnumerable<Notification> GetAllMessages(string userId)
        {
            var messages = new List<Notification>();
            using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [NotificationID], [Message], [NotificationDate], [Active], [Url], [userId] FROM [dbo].[Notifications] WHERE [Active] = 1 AND [userId] ='" + userId + "'", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                    }
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        messages.Add(item: new Notification { NotificationID = (int)reader["NotificationID"], Message = (string)reader["Message"], Url = (string)reader["Url"] });
                    }
                }
            }
            return messages;
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                MessagesHub message = new MessagesHub();
                message.SendMessages();
            }
        }
    }
```

This well show latest data when the `database table` is updated. the message will shown at runtime.
Hope this helps

Comment: You integrally copied some tutorial, without answering OP's question.

Comment: You knew that that his implementation in half baked

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path

You can refer this if I am not late ...This is working example

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
    var ws;
    var username = "JOHN";
    function startchat() {

        var log= $('log');
        var url = 'ws://<server path>/WebSocketsServer.ashx?username=' + username;

        ws = new WebSocket(url);

        ws.onerror = function (e) {
            log.appendChild(createSpan('Problem with connection: ' + e.message));
        };

        ws.onopen = function () {
            ws.send("I am Active-" +username);
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (e) {


            if (e.data.toString() == "Active?") {
                ws.send("I am Active-" + username);
            }
            else {

            }

        };

        ws.onclose = function () {
            log.innerHTML = 'Closed connection!';
        };

    }
</script>
```

```
<div id="log">

</div>
```

**Server Side in Websocketserver.ashx page**

public class WebSocketsServer : IHttpHandler
    {

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new MicrosoftWebSockets());
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Add below class in the server side

```
public class MicrosoftWebSockets : WebSocketHandler
{
    private static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();
    private string msg;

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        this.msg = this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["username"];
        clients.Add(this);
        clients.Broadcast(msg);
    }

    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        clients.Broadcast(string.Format(message));
    }

    public override void OnClose()
    {
        clients.Remove(this);
        clients.Broadcast(string.Format(msg));
    }
```

add this dll to the above class
    using Microsoft.Web.WebSockets;

I donot remeber where I got the reference ...but above code is derived from my current working application